Formulas for the Hamming weight of $x+y$
Let $x,y\in \mathbb{F}_q^n$, $\mathrm{wt}(x):=|\mathrm{supp}(x)|$ be the Hamming weight.
Case I: When $q=2$, it is easy to prove
$$ \mathrm{wt}(x+y)=\mathrm{wt}(x)+\mathrm{wt}(y)-2\left\langle x,y\right\rangle $$
Case II: When $q=3$, I also find out
$$ \mathrm{wt}(x+y)=\mathrm{wt}(x)+\mathrm{wt}(y)-\left\langle x,y\right\rangle$$
Proof of case II:
$$\begin{aligned}\mathrm{wt}(x+y)&=\#\{i:x_i+y_i\neq 0\}\\
&=\#\big((\{i: x_i\neq 0\}\cup \{i:y_i\neq 0\}) \backslash \{i:x_iy_i=2\}\big)\\
&=\mathrm{wt}(x)+\mathrm{wt}(y)-\#\{i:x_iy_i=1\}-2\#\{i:x_iy_i=2\}\\
&=\mathrm{wt}(x)+\mathrm{wt}(y)-\left\langle x,y\right\rangle
\end{aligned} $$
I wonder are there any formulas for general $q$? I cannot see any clue if I just follow a similar argument.
Any hints or references are welcomed. Thanks for help!

How do you define the inner product? If it is $\Bbb{F}_q$-valued, then neither formula is well defined. It you think of it as integer valued, then you seem to ignore the possibility $x_iy_i=4$ when $x_i=y_i=2$? Anyway, I would stick to $\Bbb{F}_q$-valued inner products, because I don't want to give up on billinearity.

Yes, it is a little weird. By the way I encounter this $2$ formulas when proving that any codeword of binary and ternary Golay codes has weight divisible by $4$ and $3$ respectively. In that case, I only need these formulas $\mod 4$ and $\mod 3$ respectively.

A fundamental obstacle here is that $\langle {\bf x,y}\rangle=\sum_i x_iy_i$ is an element of $\Bbb{F}_q$, and it is difficult to see how to do well-defined arithmetic involving both integers (=the weights) and elements of a finite field.

A kind of a remedy is our ability (by discrete Fourier transform and its inverse) to write any function $f:\Bbb{F}_q\to\Bbb{C}$ as a linear combination of additive characters $\chi_a:\Bbb{F}_q\to\Bbb{C}^*$, parametrized by $a\in\Bbb{F}_q$, and defined using the trace
$$
\chi_a(x)=\zeta^{tr(ax)},
$$
where $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/p}$, $q=p^n$, $p$ a prime, and
$$
tr(x)=x+x^p+x^{p^2}+\cdots+x^{p^{n-1}}\in\Bbb{F}_p.
$$
Observe that $\zeta^m$ is well defined when the exponent $m\in\Bbb{F}_p=\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$, because $\zeta^p=1$.
To get the Hamming weight, you want to write the function $w:\Bbb{F}_q\to\Bbb{C}$
defined via $w(0)=0,$ $w(x)=1$ whenever $x\neq0$ as a linear combination of characters $\chi_a$. The good news is that as the characters are linearly independent (Artin's lemma), we can do this for any function $\Bbb{F}_q\to\Bbb{C}$.
The Fourier transform of $w$ is
$$
\hat{w}(a):=\sum_{x\in\Bbb{F}_q}w(x)\overline{\chi_a(x)}+
=\sum_{x\in\Bbb{F}_q}\overline{\chi_a(x)}-\overline{\chi_a(0)}=
\begin{cases}
q-1,&\ \text{if $a=0$},\\
-1,&\ \text{otherwise},
\end{cases}
$$
we arrive at the identity (by inverting the above DFT, or a direct calculation)
$$
w(x)=\frac1q\left((q-1)\chi_0(x)-\sum_{a\in\Bbb{F}_q^*}\chi_a(x)\right)
=1-\frac1q\sum_{a\in\Bbb{F}_q}\chi_a(x)
$$
for all $x\in\Bbb{F}_q$.

So if ${\bf x}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_L)\in\Bbb{F}_q^L$ is any vector, its Hamming weight is given by the recipe
$$
w({\bf x})=\sum_{j=1}^Lw(x_j)=L-\sum_{j=1}^L\sum_{a\in\Bbb{F}_q}\chi_a(x_j).
$$
This may (will!!) first look like a horribly complicated way of going about it. But it is actually very useful on those occasions, when the components of the codewords
are indexed by the elements of the alphabet field $\Bbb{F}_q$, such as Reed-Solomon codes. Furthermore, we often incorporate the trace function into a definition of a code as follows. To a polynomial $f(x)\in\Bbb{F}_q[x]$ we can associate either the word $c_q(f)=(f(x))_{x\in\Bbb{F}_q}$ with components gotten by evaluating the polynomial $f$ at all the elements of the field, or the componentwise trace
$c_p(f)=(tr(f(x))_{x\in\Bbb{F}_q}$. Sometimes $x=0$ is left out of the reckoning, but its effect on the character sums is easy to take into account. The earlier
argument can be redone to yield
$$
w(c_p(f))=q-\frac1p\sum_{\ell=1}^{p-1}\sum_{x\in\Bbb{F}_q}\zeta^{\ell\, tr(f(x))}.
$$
Observe that (with the trace included in the code definition) here only characters $\chi_a$, where $a$ is in the prime field $\Bbb{F}_p$ are used. In the common
case $p=2$ this simplifies to
$$
w(c_2(f))=q-\frac12\sum_{x\in\Bbb{F}_q}(-1)^{tr(f(x))}.
$$
This is how the weights of the words of the dual BCH-codes and important other codes such as the Kasami codes can be analyzed. Character sums of the type in the last formulas are well-studied objects in number theory. Google for Weil bounds, and Carlitz-Uchiyama bounds in general. The sums required to analyze the Kasami codes don't require deep number theory.

In the 90s yours truly was involved in analyzing the properties of certain codes using the alphabet $\Bbb{Z}_4$, when instead of the Hamming metric the so called Lee metric (and variants involving Gray coding) became relevant. Discrete Fourier analysis of that metric then also played a role.

Thank you very much professor! I need some time to digest :)
